# C++ <random> distribution is not random even with seed

Tags: c++, random

I want to generate random numbers outside the main function but even when using the  library and seeding the random number generator, the output is not random. Any help is appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <time.h>

int foo(std::mt19937 rng)
{
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distr(0, 9);

    return distr(rng);
}

int main()
{
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 rng(rd());

    for (int j=0; j<10; j++)
    {
        std::cout << foo(rng) << " ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

With output

```
5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5
```

Comment: Side note: Are you sure you want to recreate `distr` every time you call the function? If not, `static` may help with that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
int foo(std::mt19937 rng)
```

You are passing the std::mt19937 generator by value, so when you pass your generator to the function, it isn't getting the numbers from the one in main, therefore creating a **copy** of that generator, which is modified inside that function only, and doesn't affect the one in main.

You should pass it by reference, so it modifies the one in main, and in each call the generator will create different numbers:

```
int foo(std::mt19937& rng)
```

Comment: Side effects <3

Answer (score 3):

Short version: Change `foo` to take a reference.

```
int foo(std::mt19937& rng);
```

When a function parameter is an object type, not a reference, that parameter is a different object from the argument object passed to it.  Here since the argument type and parameter type are the same, you're using the copy constructor.

When an entropy source like `mt19937` is passed to a distribution like `uniform_int_distribution`, the `operator()` of the distribution calls the `operator()` of the entropy source.  The `operator()` of the entropy source both returns a pseudo-random value and also modifies the entropy source so that its next call will be different.

But back in your `main`, the original object `rng` has *not* been used with a distribution.  It has only been copied, and then that copy was used.  So next time through the loop, another copy of `rng` is made.  But since this fresh object is essentially identical to the unused `rng` object, using it once is just going to produce the same results again.

A reference parameter will fix all this, since then the reference is just another name for the original `mt19937` object, so then every call to `foo` is actually using and changing that original object.